# Binding an empty Datepicker field

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to bind the `valueProperty` of a `Datepicker` to the `textProperty` of a `Label`.
If a date is picked and it is stored in the `Label` "db" then it is parsed there is no error.

But if the Label db is empty, it gives an error:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '' could not be parsed
>   at index 0

I want to be able to parse the date in both cases if **Label** "db" is empty or with a value.

Here is my updated code I use to parse.

tableviewController

```
tableview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Employee>(){
FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view.fxml"));
try{
   Parent newParent=loader.load();
   viewController sunController=loader.getController();
subController.textToDisplay.set(newValue.getDateOfBirth());

Stage stage =new Stage();
Scene scene =new Scene(newParent);
stage.setScene(scene);
```

viewController

```
@FXML private Label db;
public SimpleStringProperty textToDisplay=new SimpleStringProperty("");

private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dd/MM/yyyy);

public void update()throws IOeXCEPTION{
   FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("update.fxml"));
try{
   Parent newParent=loader.load();
   updateController sunController=loader.getController();
   subController.textToDisplay.set(LocalDate.parse(db.getText(), DATE_FORMATTER));

Stage stage =new Stage();
Scene scene =new Scene(newParent);
stage.setScene(scene);
}
@Override
public void initialize(URL location,ResourceBundle resources){
db.textProperty().bindBidirectional(textToDisplay);
}
}
```

updatebController.java

```
@FXML private DatePicker dateOfBirth;

public SimplObjectProperty<LocalDate>textToDisplay=new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location,ResourceBundle resources){
dateOfBirth.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(textToDisplay);

}
}
```

I want to be able to parse the date even if Label db is empty and the code above only works if Lable db has a value. Pls help.

Comment: I don't know JavaFX so I can't say this will be enough, but a good start would be to test the content of `db.getText()` before trying to parse it. Only call the `set` method of the display if `!db.getText().isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0):

For the binding between the DatePicker and Label, you could use the built-in [LocalDateStringConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/converter/LocalDateStringConverter.html):

```
Bindings.bindBidirectional(label.textProperty(), datePicker.valueProperty(), new LocalDateStringConverter());
```

When the DatePicker is empty, the label will also be empty and an exception won't be thrown, allowing for continued use

Note: The label won't update to an empty String until the DatePicker loses focus

With this you shouldn't need the intermediate property "textToDisplay", instead you could replace this line:

```
subController.textToDisplay.set(newValue.getDateOfBirth());
```

with:

```
datePicker.setValue(newValue.getDateOfBirth());
```

Assuming the above returns a LocalDate

---

Here's a quick example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    Label label = new Label();
    Bindings.bindBidirectional(label.textProperty(), datePicker.valueProperty(), new LocalDateStringConverter());
    Button today = new Button("Set today's date");
    today.setOnAction(event-> datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now()));
    Button clear = new Button("Clear date");
    clear.setOnAction(event-> datePicker.setValue(null));

    VBox root = new VBox(5, datePicker,
            new HBox(5, new Label("Date of Birth: "), label),
            new HBox(5, today, clear));
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setFillWidth(false);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 100);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```